# Getting encoding error while writing data to csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
from tweetpy import *
import re
import json
from pprint import pprint
import csv

# Import the necessary methods from "twitter" library
from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError, TwitterStream

# Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
ACCESS_TOKEN =  ''
ACCESS_SECRET = ''
CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''

oauth = OAuth(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

# Initiate the connection to Twitter Streaming API
twitter_stream = TwitterStream(auth=oauth)

# Get a sample of the public data following through Twitter
iterator = twitter_stream.statuses.filter(track="#kindle",language="en",replies="all")
 # Print each tweet in the stream to the screen

 # Here we set it to stop after getting 10000000 tweets.
 # You don't have to set it to stop, but can continue running
 # the Twitter API to collect data for days or even longer.

tweet_count = 10000000

file = "C:\\Users\\WELCOME\\Desktop\\twitterfeeds.csv"
with open(file,"w") as csvfile:
    fieldnames=['Username','Tweet','Timezone','Timestamp','Location']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for tweet in iterator:
        #pprint(tweet)
        username = str(tweet['user']['screen_name'])
        tweet_text = str(tweet['text'])
        user_timezone = str(tweet['user']['time_zone'])
        tweet_timestamp=str(tweet['created_at'])
        user_location = str(tweet['user']['location'])
        print tweet
        tweet_count -= 1
        writer.writerow({'Username':username,'Tweet':tweet_text,'Timezone':user_timezone,'Location':user_location,'Timestamp':tweet_timestamp})

        if tweet_count <= 0:
            break
```

I am trying to write tweets to to csv file with columns `'username'`, `'Tweet'`, `'Timezone'`, `'Location'`, and `'Timestamp'`.

But I am getting the following error:

```
tweet_text = str(tweet['text'])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 139: ordinal not in range(128).
```

I know it is encoding issue but I dont know the exact position of the variable to encode.

Comment: What do you want to do with the offending character(s)?  Omit them?  Convert them to the closest ASCII equivalent?  Convert to a fixed character such as a question mark?

Comment: The answer may very well be different for Python 2 vs Python 3. Regardless, you're not opening the csv file correctly. Suggest you read the documentation (in both versions) where how to do so correctly is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use Python 3, because the Python 2 `csv` module doesn't do encodings well.
2. Use `open` with the `encoding` and `newline` options.
3. Remove `str` conversion (In Python 3 `str` is Unicode strings already.

Result:

```
with open(file,"w",encoding='utf8',newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames=['Username','Tweet','Timezone','Timestamp','Location']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for tweet in iterator:
        username = tweet['user']['screen_name']
        tweet_text = tweet['text']
        user_timezone = tweet['user']['time_zone']
        tweet_timestamp = tweet['created_at']
        user_location = tweet['user']['location']
            .
            .
            .
```

If using Python 2, get the 3rd party `unicodecsv` module to overcome `csv` shortcomings.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to transform all your unicode data

```
tweet['text'].encode("ascii", "replace")
or
tweet['text'].encode("ascii", "ignore") # if you want skip char
```